# Header redirect after a certain period not working

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, http

I have the following :

```
header( "refresh:5;url=http://linkhere.com/caretech/resetpassword/reset_p/'.'$random_key'" );
```

I want it to redirect after 5 seconds , but I keep on getting the following error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/caretech/application/controllers/resetpassword.php:94)
>
> Filename: controllers/resetpassword.php
>
> Line Number: 117

And nothing happens later after the error. 
What is the right syntax to do this?

Comment: `ob_start();` ///first line of code and `ob_end_flush();` in last line of your php code

Comment: call `header()` before any other output.

Answer (score 1):

Headers need to be sent before any HTML content. Make sure you leave out any HTML that is above the header function.

Answer (score 0):

Add ob_start(); at the top of the document. This should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

header() must be used before the output is sent

Comment: Adding an example, or a link to the original PHP documentation will probably make your answer more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

put `ob_start();` in your first line
and
 put
`ob_end_flush();` in last line of code.